# Override Application.Doevents() in C# so it is disabled in Debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, remote-debugging, debug-symbols

I am debugging an app that was ported from vb6. It has Application.Doevents littered all over the place which is fine except when I am stepping in the debugger. As soon as I step over an Application.DoEvents() control is transferred to some random area which is expected depending on what is pending in the message pump. How can I elegantly override this method in one place at the application level so it works like this (pseudo code)

```
protected override void Application.Doevents()
{
  if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
     Application.Doevents()
}
```

without putting #ifdef DEBUG's all over the place. 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need - or possibility - to override it.
Just create a static class with a static method in it and put the code you want to have inside. Change all calls to `Application.DoEvents` to calls to that static method.

Comment: thanks to you and similar answer from Jon Skeet. Will do as per your advise.

Answer (score 1):

You can't override it. It's a static method. However, you could easily write your own class and replace all current calls to `Application.DoEvents` with `CustomApplication.DoEvents`, for example.

(Personally I don't think it's "fine" for an application to be peppered with `DoEvents` calls in the first place, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Can I mark your answer also as correct ? Dont know how to mark two answers as correct. thanks

Answer (score 1):

> It has Application.Doevents littered all over the place which is fine except when I am stepping in the debugger.

**No, it's not fine.** Not *with* the debugger attached, not *without* the debugger attached. The solution you've proposed is the wrong one. You need to eliminate it completely, not just hide it during debug mode, the time when you'll be most likely to notice the resulting bugs and side-effects.

Do a global search and replace, and comment out every line where that function is called. Then debug the resulting code to find out where it breaks and what you need to do to fix it.

*Hint*: Don't perform long-running or CPU-intensive tasks on the UI thread. Spin off a separate thread for this. The [`BackgroundWorker` component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) is an extremely convenient way of doing so, comfortable even for someone who is not comfortable working with multiple threads yet.

`Application.DoEvents` is a bug waiting to happen. Don't let it bite you. The frustrating behavior you're seeing in the debugger is *exactly* the same thing that's happening *all* the time inside of your app's code. And *whatever you do*, don't ship code containing calls to `Application.DoEvents` that you haven't *thoroughly* debugged.

Comment: That's a little exaggerated.  `DoEvents()` is (almost always) evil but if you inherit a codebase with lots of calls, and it is working, leave it alone.

Comment: @Henk - I don't think it's exaggerated at all. And more to the point, disabling it in Debug mode but leaving it enabled in Release mode is *clearly* the wrong solution. That's just a disaster waiting to happen, shipping code like that that hasn't been thoroughly debugged. There's only one real solution for this problem.

Comment: @Cody: Debugging != Testing. And it is working code, so a major overhaul to retro-fit a best-practice is just silly.

Comment: @Henk - You make a lot of assumptions that are explicitly not stated in the question. I'm not really sure why you'd need to step through code that's working fine in a debugger at all. If it were "working code", he wouldn't be trying to debug it.

Comment: Oh come on. The OP inherits a ported app, and probably has to fix/extend a little. That's a good reason for this question, not for a major fix of what isn't really broken.

Comment: Cody, Agree in a perfect world with unlimited time to finish a project I would do as per your suggestion. In future when I have time I will clean up but for now I just wanted a quick fix for this. thx

Answer (score -1):

Put the definition of the override in #ifdef DEBUG.